# Use interface as enum

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, enums

How I usually do things is this:

```
enum tmp {
  a,
  b
}

const doStuff = (val: tmp) => {
  console.log(val);
}

doStuff(tmp.b); // logs 1
```

But a library I use is doing smth like this:

```
interface tmpMap {
  a: 0;
  b: 1;
}

const tmp: tmpMap;
```

So I tried doing this:

```
const doStuff = (val: tmpMap) => {
  console.log(val);
}

doStuff(tmp.b);
```

But this throws a bunch of errors, and just doesn't work.

> Variable 'tmp' is used before being assigned.

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'tmpMap'.

Here's a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=16&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjAWwA4Fk4eQbwChlk4AuZABgG5jkAjCgRloF9DCEB7EAZzFSYK6bLlqce-ZABMuAZTABXGDGQBeZAAoAbnAA2wzDgwBKdQD4Cdbny56IAOj1cA5jv0m2HWQuUxNIg70nkA) to playground.

Is there a way to use this setup the same way as the enum setup?

Comment: `const tmp: tmpMap` is not valid code - you have to actually assign a value

Comment: and even if you did set a value, `tmp.b` is not of type `tmpMap` -- have to either update the type of `val` to `number` or pass in the full `tmp` object

Comment: Yes, it's invalid. But still, it somehow works in the library code

Comment: how are you importing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjAWwA4Fk4eQbwChlk4AuZABgG5jkAjCgRloF9DCB6T5ATQHsArgHIANqOQALOADcUYfqQRhBccQE9SAZy3AA5iFSSUCfiC1g44QgBMICUXCgmzF1JgrpsuWoVPmwZBt%20AGUVGBhkAF5kAAoZNU9MHAwAbQBrCHV%20SK8UgF0ASmiAPgI6fy1%20UQgAOlF%20PXi1QrYOYLDBCNiAFlagA)

```
interface tmpMap {
  a: 0;
  b: 1;
}

// You'll have to actually assign the constant
declare const tmp: tmpMap;

const doStuff = (val: tmpMap[keyof tmpMap]) => {
  console.log(val);
}

doStuff(tmp.b);
```

Comment: This `tmpMap[keyof tmpMap]` works. But why?

Comment: Because you're asking for an object value and that's the syntax for typing the object values. `keyof tmp` gives `a | b`, `tmpMap[a | b]` gives `0 | 1`